# use controller in helper

Tags: cakephp

In my cakephp application i need to use my controller in helper.php. Its not working. will any one explain it with little syntax?

Comment: Are you using version 1.1 or 1.2?

Answer (score 3):

I really hate thinking that code can tell me how to think instead of me telling it what to do ... anyway ... here is an example for loading the controller rendering the page, and it can load any controller inside the helper.

```
<?Php
class HelperNameHelper extends AppHelper{

    private $controller;

    public function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($view, $settings);

        $this->controller=$this->loadController();

    }

    protected function loadController($name=null){
        if (is_null($name)) $name=$this->params['controller'];
        $className = ucfirst($name) . 'Controller';
        list($plugin, $className) = pluginSplit($className, true);
        App::import('Controller', $name);
        $cont = new $className;
        $cont->constructClasses();
        $cont->request=$this->request;
        return $cont;
    }
}
```

EDIT: just realiced this is such an old post :( ... this is working in cakephp 2.2.3

Comment: +1 for ***I really hate thinking that code can tell me how to think instead of me telling it what to do*** Although it must be always noted that the conventions exist for a purpose. If you absolutely understand what you are at and what is at stake, this is a good example of manipulating the conventions for greater benefit. BTW, `App::import()` exists for developers who understand what they are doing, else it simply wont exist. Others probably advocated conventions to stop newbies from exploiting methods without understanding the side effects.

Comment: rules are meant to be broken :P

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are not designed to have access to the controller.  If you're trying to access the controller you may want to rethink your application design.

I actually had this same problem myself.  I have a CakePHP 1.1 application where I was accessing the controller by passing the name of the controller as a parameter to the view.  After trying to upgrade the code to work with 1.2 I realized that this was bad design.  It was my first experience with CakePHP and MVC, so I chalked that up as a lesson learned.

MVC requires some up-front design to make sure that you're putting your functions in the right places (controller, model, or view).

(P.S. You can also try the #cakephp channel on irc.freenode.net)

Answer (score 0):

Its an MVC.

You shouldn't use a Controller in your helper, rather use your helper in your controller.

Why would wan't to do that in the first place.

Read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller